# UIViewController section headers not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with several headers. 
They are implemented as section headers. 
Each header belongs to its own controller and those controllers conform to `MyHeaderProtocol`.

Basically I have an array of controllers and request header cell from each of them when necessary.

So:

1. `collectionView(:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at)` is called and returns actual view. View is properly set, has good frame size etc. Just in case I color view there to purple - but I can't see it on screen.
2. `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` is called and return good CGSize values.

Collection view is displayed but instead of all those headers I see just empty white space. 
So the issue is - both necessary methods do display a header section are called but section header isn't displayed (yet space is reserved for it).

Here is simplified version of my code:

```
protocol MyHeaderProtocol: class {
    var nib: UINib { get }
    var cellReuseIdentifier: String { get }
    // Will dequeue UICollectionViewCell using dequeueReusableSupplementaryView and set data for this cell
    func setupHeader(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?
    func getCellHeight()
}

class MyCollectionView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView
    private var headers: [MyHeaderProtocol] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        // it will instantiate controllers conformed to MyHeaderProtocol and append them to header array
        setUpHeaders() 
        registerHeaders()
    }

    private func setUpHeaders()  {
        let headerOne = SimpleHeader1(withModel: viewModel)
        headers.append(headerOne)
        let headerTwo = SimpleHeader2(withModel: viewModel)
        headers.append(headerTwo)
    }

    private func registerHeaders() {
        for header in headers {
            collectionView.register(header.nib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: header.cellReuseIdentifier)
        }
    }

}

extension MyCollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return headers.count + 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == headers.count {
            // If section isn't a header section - we return actual cells
            return viewModel.people.count
        } else {
            // if it is a header - we return only section, no intems
            return 0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var view : UICollectionReusableView?
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            // if it is a header
            if indexPath.section < headers.count {
                let header = headers[indexPath.section]
                view = header.setupHeader(collectionView: collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
                // to test that header is visible
                view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
            }
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            break
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
            break
        }
        return view ?? UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}

extension MyCollectionView : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        var size = CGSize.zero
        // If that's header - return non-Zero size
        if section < headers.count {
            let header = headers[section]
            size = CGSize.init(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: header.getCellHeight())
        }   
        return size
    }
}
```

Comment: to save me time building this, could you please share your setupHeaders function, or even better, post a github link for your whole project?

Comment: I won't be able to post the project to the Guthub. But I may have time later to set up a test project. I'll add `setupHeaders` but I don't think it will help a lot.

Comment: ok i have tried to help with what info you've provided. But a test project would be great to better understand your problem.

Comment: when you put a breakpoint in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, is the `view` nil when setting the background color?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be with your custom `MyHeaderProtocol` protocol. This function in particular:

```
func setupHeader(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?
```

You have to return a header here, otherwise this function `collectionView(:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at` will not produce expected behaviour:

```
var view : UICollectionReusableView?
view = header.setupHeader(collectionView: collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

So try this instead:

```
func setupHeader(collectionView: UICollectionView, headerForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. LLVM does check types and if there is any type issues I won't be able to return wrong type from this method. In fact `UICollectionViewCell` inherits from `UICollectionReusableView`. So that should be fine. Also header classes `SimpleHeader1` and `SimpleHeader2` are not `UIView` classes. As I mentioned they are controllers (or managers), they instantiate corresponding `SimpleHeader1View` class from xib.

Comment: I think this is not documented to use a `UICollectionViewCell` as a header.